# Use a single VM with Vagrant to host Docker Containers across multiple projects

Tags: docker, vagrant, virtualbox

I have two separate projects/src/code repos, using Vagrant to run an application in docker containers.

I am using Vagrant with a CentOS7 Host VM to host docker containers (https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/docker/basics.html). I am using a duplicate copy of the CentOS7 VM Vagrantfile (`Vagranfile.host`) in each project.

```
- proj1/
-- Vagrantfile
-- Vagrantfile.host
- proj2/
-- Vagrantfile
-- Vagrantfile.host
```

Each `Vagrantfile` points to `Vagrantfile.host` to spin up a CentOS VM to host the Docker containers.

The only difference (effectively for this question) between the two projects is that the `Vagrantfile` in `proj1` points to a different docker image than the one in `proj2`.

When I do `vagrant up` in each project folder, each one create's it's own CentOS7 VM instantiation, so I end up running two separate VirtualBox VMs.

Is there a way to change one or both of the `Vagrantfile` files so that I end up only spinning up a single VM, and the containers both run in the same VirtualBox VM?

Comment: this community is all about **programming**, not server administration

Comment: Looking at the vagrant tag, I would say there are many questions like this on SO. I view vagrant as something more that developers use than SA's. If submitted a ticket to a help desk, I would guess that many of them wouldn't even know what Vagrant is

Comment: [Multi-Container Docker with YAML and Vagrant](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/02/11/multi-container-docker-yaml-vagrant/) is probably a good example to start. The setup is very doable though.

Comment: the fact that many people post about the wrong topics doesnt change the fact that they're about ... **wrong topics**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work. Not quite the way I wanted, but documenting for anyone who finds this question later. Point both Docker Vagrantfile's to the same Vagrantfile.host for their linux parent.

```
   - proj1/
   -- Vagrantfile --> ./Vagrantfile.host
   -- Vagrantfile.host
   - proj2/
   -- Vagrantfile --> ../proj1/Vagrantfile.host
```